# Solving an ODE which seems not able to sepearte the variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here is my ODE:
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y-1}{2x}+\dfrac{3}{2}$$
with initial condition $y(1)=0$.

I tried to write:
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y-1+3x}{2x}$$
but I do not know how to move on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to solve $y'(x)+P(x)y=Q(x)$ ?

Comment: No, is it a standard form such that I can find it in the ODE books?

Comment: @nam Yes, the procedure is called the method of integrating factors. It is applicable for any first order linear equation.

Comment: This is know as a first order linear differential equation. Any textbook will have it.

Comment: Thank you Michael, Ian and Aniket. I got the hints and I am looking up the clues to solve. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an ODE like the following:
$$y' + P(x)y = Q(x)$$
You can create an integrating factor $\lambda$ such that:
$$\lambda(x) = e^{\int P(x)\ dx}\implies\lambda'(x) = P(x)\lambda(x)$$
Then, multiplying your original equation by $\lambda$ you find:
$$\lambda(x)y' + \lambda(x)P(x)y = Q(x)\lambda(x)$$
$$\left(\lambda(x)\cdot y\right)' = Q(x)\lambda(x)$$
So we get that
$$y = \frac{1}{\lambda(x)}\int Q(x)\lambda(x)\ dx$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: given that  $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y-1}{2x}+\frac{3}{2}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{2x}-\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{3}{2}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\left(-\frac{1}{2x}\right)y=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2x}$$
comparing the above equation with the linear D.E. $\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y =Q(x)$, we get 
$$P(x)=-\frac{1}{2x},\ \ Q(x)=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2x}$$

Then the general solution is given as $$ye^{\int P(x)dx}=\int e^{\int P(x)dx}Q(x)\ dx+C$$